# Where is my Bitizen?

Tags: tiny-tower

I did a time travel and it told me one of my people was "lost." I went and looked through all of my apartments, but all the spots were filled. It says 309 bitizens in the top left corner, so I know one's missing but I don't know where.

Comment: Did you have all residential floors full?

Comment: Yeah and they all appear full-i checked through all of them.

Comment: How many residential floors do you have?

Comment: I have 61 residential

Comment: but if you have 61 residentials.. 61 x 5 bitizens per residential... 305. You should have a maximum of 305.

Answer (score 1):

Based on research and calculations, that person will be gone forever. Unless another Bitizen takes the empty spot, that is.

The most reasonable answer to this question is that it was meant to happen, and you will not find the missing Bitizen. According to the [Tiny Tower Wiki](http://tinytower.wikia.com/wiki/Bux), the creators of Tiny Towers intentionally developed this function to encourage players to stop cheating.

Answer (score 0):

It is random, bitizens can die or get lost. I quit the game for about three months and when i came back to it a message popped up saying that one of my bitizens died in a car crash.

Answer (score 0):

It happened bacuse you probaly tried to "Time travel"(Move the clock backwards/forwards) for some reason.